# reset component based on its original mxml

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, components, mxml

I have a datagrid that allows user to change and save columns widths and visibility. I'd like to add a reset button that would just reset the datagrid to it's original mxml. This is the original datagrid code.

```
<mx:DataGrid x="10" y="47" height="159" width="250" dataProvider="{acOffspring}" id="offspring_dg">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Tag" visible="true" dataField="animal_ptag" width="121"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Sex" dataField="animal_sex" width="45"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Birth Date" visible="true" dataField="animal_birthdate" width="82"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name" visible="false" dataField="animal_name" width="82"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Status" visible="false" dataField="status_status" width="82"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Breed" visible="false" dataField="breed_breed" width="82"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: After a user has changed some of the columns widths and visibility, how can I reset my datagrid to display as it did with its original mxml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options that I see:

The first is to destroy the component and create a new instance of it.  Like this:

```
container.removeChild(offspring_dg);
offspring_dg= new myDataGrid();
container.addChild(offspring_dg);
```

The second is to store the default values in some manner and then do a loop and reset all the relevant properties.  Something like this:

```
Column1InitialWidth = offspring_dg.columns[0].width
Column1InitialVisibility = offspring_dg.columns[0].visibility
etc...
```

When it comes time to reset them just do the same thing in reverse:

```
offspring_dg.columns[0].width = Column1InitialWidth
offspring_dg.columns[0].visibility = Column1InitialVisibility
```

I'm sure this approach could be encapsulated a bit more if you're dealing with a lot of columns.